# Error when trying to read SQLite database Windows Universal Apps VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, win-universal-app

I am using the following code to try to access a database and fill a combo box:

```
            With cmbPaciente.Items
               Dim sConexao As String = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "\Banco\Deal.db")
               Dim aConexao As New SQLiteConnection(sConexao)
               Dim Comando = aConexao.CreateCommand("select Name from PData")
               Dim Resultado As String = aConexao.Query(Comando)
               For Each item In Resultado
                   .Add(item)
               Next
            End With
```

But I am getting this error:

```
BC32050  VB.NET Type parameter '' for '' cannot be inferred.
```

Already tried with:

```
            With cmbPaciente.Items
               Dim sConexao As String = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "\Banco\Deal.db")
               Dim aConexao As New SQLiteConnection(sConexao)
               Dim Comando = aConexao.CreateCommand("select Name from PData")
               Dim Resultado As String = aConexao.Execute(Comando)
               For Each item In Resultado
                   .Add(item)
               Next
            End With
```

With no success also. Of course I am doing something wrong, but my knowledge isnt enough to understand what. Any clues will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `CreateCommand` for reading data from Database, and I found a little problem with your code `Dim aConexao As New SQLiteConnection(sConexao)`, in an UWP app, it should be something like this:

```
Dim aConexao As New SQLiteConnection(New SQLitePlatformWinRT(), sConexao)
```

Here is my sample:

XAML code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbPaciente" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Symbol}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
<Button Content="create database" Click="Button_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,30,0,0" />
<Button Content="read data from database" Click="Button_Click_1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,100,0,0" />
```

Code behind:

```
Private combolist As New ObservableCollection(Of Stockvb)()
Private Sub showComboBoxItem()
    With cmbPaciente.Items
        Dim sConexao As String = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Deal.db")
        Dim aConexao As New SQLiteConnection(New SQLitePlatformWinRT(), sConexao)
        For Each item As Stockvb In aConexao.Table(Of Stockvb)()
            Dim newlist As New Stockvb()
            newlist.Id = item.Id
            newlist.Symbol = item.Symbol
            combolist.Add(newlist)
        Next
        cmbPaciente.ItemsSource = combolist
    End With
End Sub

Private Async Function CheckFileExists(fileName As String) As Task(Of Boolean)
    Try
        Dim store = Await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName)
        Return True
    Catch
    End Try
    Return False
End Function

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If Not CheckFileExists("Deal.db").Result Then
        Dim spath As String = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Deal.db")
        Dim db As New SQLiteConnection(New SQLitePlatformWinRT(), spath)
        db.CreateTable(Of Stockvb)()

        For i As Integer = 0 To 5
            Dim stocklist As New Stockvb()
            stocklist.Id = i
            stocklist.Symbol = "Item" + i.ToString()
            db.Insert(stocklist)
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    showComboBoxItem()
End Sub
```

And here is the Stockvb class:

```
Public Class Stockvb
    <PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement>
    Public Property Id() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Id
        End Get
        Set
            m_Id = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Id As Integer

    <MaxLength(8)>
    Public Property Symbol() As String
        Get
            Return m_Symbol
        End Get
        Set
            m_Symbol = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Symbol As String
End Class
```

I changed your database's name to "Deal.db" in my code.

Comment: Thanks Grace, but which Imports are you using? I cant use SQLitePlatformWinRT() in my code as it gives me an error.

I am using these:
Imports SQLite
Imports Windows.Storage
Imports System.Data

Comment: @SpartacusRocha Imports SQLite.Net
Imports SQLite.Net.Interop
Imports SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT
Imports Windows.Storage.  You will need to install SQLite.Net-PCL from Nuget tool, and please don't forget to add reference of SQLite for universal App Platform. [Here is my demo.](https://github.com/GraceFeng/UWP-SQLite-VB)